# Removing Elements from a range

Tags: python, range

i am a beginner and i would like to know how to remove the multiples of 11 and 4 from this the range. I would like to include all other numbers excluding 4, 11 and their variable. Is there a way of doing this without individual writing each code snippet?

```
for i in range(1,101):
    print (2**i)-1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> [i for i in range(1,101) if i%4!=0 and i%11!=0]

[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9,
 10, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19,
 21, 23, 25, 26, 27, 29,
 30, 31, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39,
 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 49,
 50, 51, 53, 54, 57, 58, 59,
 61, 62, 63, 65, 67, 69,
 70, 71, 73, 74, 75, 78, 79,
 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89,
 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98]
```

Comment: +1, though you can simplify that to `[i for i in range(1,101) if i%4 and i%11]`